# Exception accessing Blobstore from REST webservice

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey, blobstore

I'm trying to upload images to my REST webservice (using Jersey) on Google App Engine.

This is my method:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadImage(@Context HttpServletRequest request){
        BlobstoreService bs = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
        bs.createUploadUrl("/upload");

        Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobFields = bs.getUploads(request);
        List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobFields.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue();
        if (blobKeys != null && !blobKeys.isEmpty()) {
            BlobKey blobKey = blobKeys.get(0);
            System.out.println("MY KEY: "+blobKey.getKeyString());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

But i get this exception:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from a blob upload callback request.
```

on this line:

```
Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobFields = bs.getUploads(request);
```

Where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check below examples.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/

You need to set result of createUploadUrl() to action attribute on form tag.